# Offline Sync Files : Upload ArrayList or Upload in a for loop

Tags: java, android, performance, asynchronous, upload

I am basically a Java Developer with just Basic information about Android Development. I have developed a web endpoint that accepts a file and some other parameters. The java code is

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/beneficiary/initial/inspection/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String uploadInitialInspectionPhoto(@RequestParam(value = "uploadImg") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("hdId") Long hdId, @RequestParam("toRegId") String toRegId,
        @RequestParam(value = "remark", required = false) String remark,
        @RequestParam(value="latitude")String latitude,
        @RequestParam(value="longitude")String longitude) {
//.... Method Code
}
```

My Android developer says it takes 10 minutes to upload 10 files on an async background thread as it has to hit the URL 10 times. She suggests that I change the API to accept ArrayList instead. i.e change  the interface to

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/beneficiary/initial/inspection/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String uploadInitialInspectionPhoto(@RequestParam(value = "uploadImg") MultipartFile[] files,
        @RequestParam("hdId") Long[] hdIds, @RequestParam("toRegId") String[] toRegIds,
        @RequestParam(value = "remark", required = false) String[] remarks,
        @RequestParam(value="latitude")String[] latitudes,
        @RequestParam(value="longitude")String[] longitudes) {
     for (int idx =  0; idx < hdIds.length; idx++)
     {
        //... Same code as in current method
        officerSvc.save(.....)
     }
}
```

Note the plural forms and the []

My basic question is : Does the suggestion to change the api to accept an ArrayList/Array instead of a single instance so as to increase performance of the upload with it's merits? Fact or Fiction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It will save the time to create connections between client and server.
But It is not very much, 1-2 seconds probably.